# How to count value with changing margin in WEBI?

Tags: business-objects, webi

​Hi Guys,
it sounds easy but it doesn't... Customer got several invoices in specific periods (months).
We want to calculate the final amount (total+margin). The problem is that margin is changing during the periods.
​I want to get 7142,76 in one cell (for summary). As you can see it's feasible in table but not in single formula as I am getting #MULTIVALUE
I guess the rootcause is margin which variable is quite simple:

```
=If([Doc Year]="2022" And [Doc Period]>=1 And [Doc Period]<=2) Then 0 Else If ([Doc Year]="2022" And [Doc Period]>2 And [Doc Period]<7) Then 4,5 Else 10
```

Thanks

[image]

The 6835,18 value is calcuated by:

```
​=Sum([Term Invoice Line Net Amount] ForAll ([Customer];[Doc Year];[Doc Period];[vMargin]))
```

​Cant figure out how to calculate total with margin...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will use my findings.
Finally I tried to focus just on counting the margin amount (307,58) and finally got it:

```
Sum([Term Invoice Line Net Amount]*[vMargin]/100)
```

Then final formula is:

```
=Sum([Term Invoice Line Net Amount] ForAll ([Customer];[Doc Year];[Doc Period];[vMargin]))+Sum([Term Invoice Line Net Amount]*[vMargin]/100)
```

and it works!

Previously I had #MULTIVALUE as I was counting amount with margin as below:

```
=Sum([Term Invoice Line Net Amount]*([vMargin]/100))
```

But the correct formula is:

```
=Sum([Term Invoice Line Net Amount]*[vMargin]/100)
```

small diffrence but crucial